# Run standalone android studio designer to preview layout code?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm curious is there a way to run android studio designer tool without loading whole android studio?

I'm asking because I'm an emacs user and I can do everything in emacs except previewing layouts (or making changes to them visually). As I understood android studio is open source and designer tool is located in android plugin to jetbrains community edition [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/android/tree/master/designer).

I know nothing about android studio source code, so can anyone who knows explain me if this is possible at all - to extract only visual editor to separate application which accepts file name of layout xml file path as argument (mb additional argument of current project settings if needed) and show visual editor for this layout file, or at least rendering it to image so that I can see how it will look like on device specified in build settings? Thx.